# Combine 2 tables without primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables and wanna combine as below

Table **Student**:

```
Student ID | Student Name
-----------+-------------
100           John
101           Micheal
```

Table **Subject**:

```
Subject Name | Subject Desc
-------------+-------------
Math           Math
History        History
```

Combined:

```
Student ID | Student Name | Subject Name | Subject Desc
-----------+--------------+--------------+-------------
100           John          Math           Math 
100           John          History        History
101           Micheal       Math           Math
101           Micheal       History        History
```

I hope anyone can help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you need to use the SQL CROSS JOIN that produces a result set which is the number of rows in the first table multiplied by the number of rows in the second table (if no WHERE clause is used along with CROSS JOIN).This kind of result is called 'Cartesian Product'.

```
    SELECT [Student ID], [Student Name], [Subject Name], [Subject Desc]
    FROM Student
    CROSS JOIN
    Subject
```

Comment: Please do take the time to explain what your answer does as well. It'll help the OP understand the code you've posted.